# Removing HTML until a certain point in a file

Tags: python, html

The problem is pretty simple: 
I have a few thousand HTML files that I'd like to loop through and remove everything until the **second** instance of this:

`<!--------------------------------------------------------->`

I know how to load files, write loops, etc., in Python, but all my attempts to parse the files as text are failing.

Comment: You want to remove that from the files or just reference it to a variable?  What code are you using / what have you tried so far?

Comment: Still learning how to post questions here. The reply by Aaron below solved my problem, and thanks to your questions I know next time I'll phrase myself better, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can try [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the string, and get the stuff after the second occurrence.

```
source = "YOUR HTML FILE CONTENT"
print source.split('<!--------------------------------------------------------->')[2:]
```